# “Cannot find debug adapter for type 'dart". ”

Tags: json, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm trying to debug dart script in vs code.

Below is my launch.json -

````
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        
        {
            "name": "todoapp",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
} ```
````

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please try disabling all extensions except Dart to see if it goes away. If so, use the new "Extension Bisect" feature to track down which extension causes it. If not, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Extensions View (⇧⌘X) and search for `Dart` extension. Try to uninstall and reinstall the Dart extension, and then restart VS code to see if it works.

If it is still not working, install an older version of Dart and give it a try again.